# Ionic on Android: How to get Google Play campaign tracking parameters?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a Ionic/Cordova app with Google Analytics plugin, setup for Google Play Store campaign tracking. UTM parameters flow to Google Analytics without a problem.

However, I would like to access those parameters from my application code, to personalize the experience based on source of installation, and/or use campaign information with third party tracking solutions.

Is there a simple way to receive Play Store campaign tracking in Cordova application code, hopefully without writing native code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved it months ago, but problably needs some modifications for the last analytics plugin

Using this plugin: https://github.com/tvhnet2014/PHONEGAP-android-referrer-plugin Allows to retrieve the tracking parameters into the native android code, and stores in the application shared preferences for later retrieval.

With this [plugin https://github.com/chrisekelley/AppPreferences/](https://github.com/chrisekelley/AppPreferences/) You can access the App preferences from the javascript, so voilá, you have the data into your javascript.

Problem: The first plugin uses a custom broadcastReceiver, so probably, it crashes with the broadcastReceiver of the analytics plugin, so you will have to modify one of the plugins, to use the same broadcastReceiver.

Comment: Thanks!

Will test this over the weekend and mark as correct answer when it works

Comment: How does one accomplish a cross platform solution so that we can tracking campaign params for both iOS and Android?